# Why is https being blocked on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm creating a simple website on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using node js. I'm trying to add an SSL certificate to the EC2 instance but it keeps saying

```
"Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:443"
```

What did I miss?

EC2 Security Group:

Inbound Rules:

```
HTTP    TCP    80    0.0.0.0/0
HTTP    TCP    80    ::/0
HTTPS   TCP    443   0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS   TCP    443   ::/0
```

Outbound Rules:

```
All traffic    All    All    0.0.0.0/0
```

Node JS:

```
    var ipaddress = "0.0.0.0";
    var port = 443;

    var options = {
        key: sslKey,
        cert: sslCert,
        ca: [sslCa]
    }

    server = https.createServer(options, handleRequest);

    server.listen(port, ipaddress, function () {
        console.log("Server listening on port "+port);
    });
```

Comment: have you followed this guide? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html

Comment: are you using LB on Elastic beanstalk? if yes then do not manage ssl at instance level

Comment: Not using a LB to save $cash. I'll try out that guide.

Answer (score 3):

I know this Elastic Beanstalk stuff is not documented well, but since I did the AWS DevOps certification some time ago which covered this, I remember some points:

- You should bind your HTTP server to `0.0.0.0`. I see you already did that.
- Your app is not running with root privileges on your EB instance. Usually what they want you to do - probably for security reasons - is to proxy your connection through the nginx proxy which comes pre-configured on your instance. They pass the `PORT` environment variable to your node.js app and you should use it to listen for upstream traffic by the proxy. [1]
- For SSL termination on your nginx proxy to work, you must then configure ssl on the proxy accordingly as already pointed out correctly by vikyol. [2]
- The connection between the proxy and your app will then be unencrypted. This should not be an issue since it does not leave the machine in between.

#### Some more thoughts

- I would prefer SSL termination on the load balancer for performance reasons if you have some $$ somewhen.
- SSL Certificate management usually is much more comfortable via [ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/de/certificate-manager/) and ELB.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html

Answer (score 1):

On some Linux distros, notably Ubuntu, **non-root users cannot bind to ports less than 1024**. (See my notes below for evidence.)

There are various ways to address this. See:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bind-port-number-less-1024-non-root-access/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux

---

More generally though, to answer the question of "how to I get a SSL-secured website running on Elastic Beanstalk". I would say: *Don't terminate your TLS/SSL in your application*.

- In my experience, using an Elastic Load Balancer to terminate your SSL/TLS is an altogether far simpler solution. (If you use Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM) to issue and manage your certs). ACM will automatically update certificate before expiration too!
- If you do really want to keep your cert on-instance, then I would recommend you use a "real" web server, like `nginx` to front your nodejs process. `nginx` has facilities to install your SSL certs[1] and plugins to automate their issuance and renewal via LetsEncrypt[2]. And quite simply that's what its designed to do.

  - I don't know which specific EB platform you're using, but many of them (all of them?) come pre-installed with web server's running by default. (e.g., the docker platform runs `nginx`, the `python` platform runs apache). As such, it is likely you already have an appropriate web server installed on your EB instance.

---

The following was executed on an Ubuntu docker instance. (The command is just a one-line command to start a python HTTP server at the specified port.) You can see that port `1025` always works. But port `1023` only works as root.

```
root@24928b62f0bd:/# python3 -m http.server 1025
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 1025 (http://0.0.0.0:1025/) ...
^C
Keyboard interrupt received, exiting.
root@24928b62f0bd:/# python3 -m http.server 1023 
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 444 (http://0.0.0.0:1023/) ...
^C
Keyboard interrupt received, exiting.
root@24928b62f0bd:/# useradd bob
root@24928b62f0bd:/# su bob
$ python3 -m http.server 1025
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 1025 (http://0.0.0.0:1025/) ...
^C
Keyboard interrupt received, exiting.
$ python3 -m http.server 1023
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 1211, in <module>
    test(HandlerClass=handler_class, port=args.port, bind=args.bind)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 1185, in test
    with ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass) as httpd:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 456, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 470, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
$
```

[1] http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html
[2] https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04